How to get the least similar vectors in a vector database
Recently I learned about four-valued logic and the Catuṣkoṭi and I'm interested in applying these ideas to experiments with LLMs and embedding vectors. More specifically, given a large spectrum of opinions, I am evaluating the best methods to find contradictions within it.
Of course with typical vector databases, it's very easy to find the most similar statements, which can be easily achieved using a parameter like "top_k" in Pinecone.
But in this experiment, I would like to instead get the worst matches, so that I input an embeddings vector and get the existing embedding IDs from the vector database where the cosine similarity score is

either as low as possible (i.e. as close to -1 as possible, to see whether matches with a similarity score close to -1 might also somehow be meaningful)
or as close to zero as possible (to check whether the geometric interpretation of two vectors being "orthogonal" also has a corresponding interpretation in semantics)

Is that possible somehow, i.e. are there existing vector databases which support this?

What you're looking for is called "Dissimilarity Search". Similarity search is computationally less expensive than dissimilarity search. The domain is constrained per se, which is harder to guarantee for dissimilarity (bottom-k) search.
What this does remind me of though, is Maximal Marginal Relevance (MMR). A technique used to prioritize diversity in similarity searches. After retrieving the some n (chunk size) * k similar documents, we find the most dissimilar document to K1 (most similar result) from the rest, This is repeated till K results are retrieved, all of which are dissimilar to each other but similar to the query document.
The latter works because of a constrained domain, maybe it could be useful to you.
https://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~canf/CS533/hwSpring14/eightMinPresentations/handoutMMR.pdf
Dissimilarity search is pretty tough, because you have to calculate distances to many more samples. Think of this, we're embedding in 3 Dimensions. Embed and plot the query, draw a sphere around it till you have roughly K samples inside the sphere. Use your similarity function and select the top-k results, your domain is constrained by the sphere. This is incredibly contrived to illustrate the point over text succinctly, but such optimizations deliberately reduce the number of samples to check, so you aren't comparing all the results in your vector database.
You could also set the top_k to the number of samples in your database and select the last N results. This won't scale, though.
EDIT:
01/12/24
Qdrant's recommendation API allows you to provide negative examples that it distances results from, take a look?
https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/explore/#recommendation-api
